# Importerror: No module named time in python2.7.6 in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, ubuntu-16.04

I have a strange problem on python2.7.6 with Ubuntu :

my python 2.7.6 is installed but strangely time module is not working. my ubuntu version is 16.04

i tried installing python 2.7.16 as well but that didnt fixed the issue as

```
/usr/local/bin# python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jul 22 2019, 12:49:04)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named time
```

expected : import time should work

actual : ImportError: No module named time

How do i import time in python 2.7.6

output of :

: ls /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/

audioop.i386-linux-gnu.so            _codecs_tw.i386-linux-gnu.so       dl.i386-linux-gnu.so                 _lsprof.i386-linux-gnu.so             Python-2.7.egg-info
audioop.x86_64-linux-gnu.so          _codecs_tw.x86_64-linux-gnu.so     _elementtree.i386-linux-gnu.so       _lsprof.x86_64-linux-gnu.so           readline.i386-linux-gnu.so
_bsddb.i386-linux-gnu.so             crypt.i386-linux-gnu.so            _elementtree.x86_64-linux-gnu.so     mmap.i386-linux-gnu.so                readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_bsddb.x86_64-linux-gnu.so           crypt.x86_64-linux-gnu.so          fpectl.i386-linux-gnu.so             mmap.x86_64-linux-gnu.so              resource.i386-linux-gnu.so
bz2.i386-linux-gnu.so                _csv.i386-linux-gnu.so             fpectl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so           _multibytecodec.i386-linux-gnu.so     resource.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
bz2.x86_64-linux-gnu.so              _csv.x86_64-linux-gnu.so           future_builtins.i386-linux-gnu.so    _multibytecodec.x86_64-linux-gnu.so   _sqlite3.i386-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_cn.i386-linux-gnu.so         _ctypes.i386-linux-gnu.so          future_builtins.x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _multiprocessing.i386-linux-gnu.so    _sqlite3.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_cn.x86_64-linux-gnu.so       _ctypes_test.i386-linux-gnu.so     _hashlib.i386-linux-gnu.so           _multiprocessing.x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _ssl.i386-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_hk.i386-linux-gnu.so         _ctypes_test.x86_64-linux-gnu.so   _hashlib.x86_64-linux-gnu.so         nis.i386-linux-gnu.so                 _ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_hk.x86_64-linux-gnu.so       _ctypes.x86_64-linux-gnu.so        _hotshot.i386-linux-gnu.so           nis.x86_64-linux-gnu.so               termios.i386-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_iso2022.i386-linux-gnu.so    _curses.i386-linux-gnu.so          _hotshot.x86_64-linux-gnu.so         ossaudiodev.i386-linux-gnu.so         termios.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_iso2022.x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _curses_panel.i386-linux-gnu.so    imageop.i386-linux-gnu.so            ossaudiodev.x86_64-linux-gnu.so       _testcapi.i386-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_jp.i386-linux-gnu.so         _curses_panel.x86_64-linux-gnu.so  _json.i386-linux-gnu.so              parser.i386-linux-gnu.so              _testcapi.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_jp.x86_64-linux-gnu.so       _curses.x86_64-linux-gnu.so        _json.x86_64-linux-gnu.so            parser.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_kr.i386-linux-gnu.so         dbm.i386-linux-gnu.so              linuxaudiodev.i386-linux-gnu.so      pyexpat.i386-linux-gnu.so
_codecs_kr.x86_64-linux-gnu.so       dbm.x86_64-linux-gnu.so            linuxaudiodev.x86_64-linux-gnu.so    pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Comment: Can you check the Python lib directory on your system for time.so ? (As a reference, on my system it is at: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so)

Comment: `/usr/local/bin#` → You are working as root?

Comment: yes, i am working as a root

Comment: @gsr : kindly suggest command to check the same

Comment: guys please help

Comment: Please share output of "which python". And if it is /usr/local/bin/python, then please share output of "ls  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so" and "ls  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload".

Comment: @gsr : which python -----> /usr/bin/python:

 cd  /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/  ------> no "time.so" file under this folder

Comment: Are there any other files in that directory ? My installation has 60 .so files. Looks like your installation is broken. It will not be easy to debug this issue remotely. Best option maybe to do a fresh installation.

Comment: @gsr : - output is pasted above, in the main question , please check

Comment: @gsr : Please check my output in the main question section and let me know

Comment: Looks like you have a mix of 32-bit (i386) and 64-bit (x86_64) binaries. I'm not aware of the nuances of such mixed installs and hence, cannot help you troubleshoot this. Maybe you can look at https://serverfault.com/questions/60619/fedora-usr-lib-vs-usr-lib64 or google further for better solutions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems time package is not install, you can try by installing time package using below command.

pip install times

or

sudo pip install times.

and then try?

Comment: `time` is a standard library module.